# Selecting a specific character from a VBA string

Tags: string, excel, vba

How do I select a specific character from a string in VBA? The strings first characters always differ but the last 6 does not.

Say the string is: A = 1/2’’ NPT

Here I would like to get the ‘ closest to 2.

If the string is: A = 1-1/2’’ NPT

I would still want the ‘ closest to 2.

Any help would be appreciated!
- Remi

Comment: You say the last six characters don't differ. So you're always going to want to select `’`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub test()

    Dim myStr As String

    myStr = "A = 1/2"" NPT"

    myStr = Split(myStr, """")(0)
    myStr = Split(myStr, "= ")(1)

    MsgBox myStr

End Sub
```